# Unable to access updated global variables in api

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python and unable to update the global variable.

curl 127.0.0.1:5000/test always enters the if condition. I only want it to enter once. When I invoke /test second time, it does not retain provided_datetime to 1

Thoughts?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import boto3
import datetime
app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        data={"data":"Hello World"}
        return data

class Test(Resource):
    provided_datetime = 0

    def getvalue(self):
        self.provided_datetime=1
        return self.provided_datetime

    def get(self):
        if self.provided_datetime < 1:
            self.getvalue()
            print('executed')
        return self.provided_datetime

api.add_resource(HelloWorld,'/hello')

api.add_resource(Test,'/test')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Thank you!

Comment: `Test.get()` returns `self.provided_datetime`, which is always 0.  It never changes.  The call to `self.getvalue()` is useless because you're not actually using the value that is returned.

Comment: you shouldn't be using a global variable here to begin with. Use the instance variable, `self.provided_datetime`

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga. I only want the control to go into if condition once but it is entering each time